# prototype and jquery with node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, prototype

I'm have a js file that I'm trying to use in a node.js app.  I've tried everything I can think of and continue to have issues of either methods not defined or objects not existing.

This is the js file I'm including:

```
    var $ = require('jquery');

var CountdownTimer = function(options){

  this.settings = $.extend(
            {   
                          seconds: 60,
                          onTick: null,
                          onComplete: null
            },options || {});
};

CountdownTimer.prototype = {

  start: function(){
    this.reset();
    this.interval = window.setInterval($.proxy(this.tick, this), 1000);
  },

  reset: function(){
    if(this.interval){
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
    this.secondsRemaining = this.settings.seconds;
    this.tick();

  },

  tick: function(){
    this.hoursRemaining         = Math.floor(this.secondsRemaining / (60 * 60));

    this.minutesRemaining       = this.secondsRemaining % (60 * 60);
    this.hourMinutesRemaining   = Math.floor(this.minutesRemaining / 60);

    this.minuteSecondsRemaining = this.minutesRemaining % 60;
    this.hourSecondsRemaining   = Math.ceil(this.minuteSecondsRemaining);

    this.fHrs = this.formatNumber(this.hoursRemaining);
    this.fMins = this.formatNumber(this.hourMinutesRemaining);
    this.fSecs = this.formatNumber(this.hourSecondsRemaining);

    if(this.settings.onTick){
      console.log(this.settings.onTick);
      this.settings.onTick();
    }
    if(this.secondsRemaining == 0){
      this.complete();
    }
    this.secondsRemaining -= 1;
  },

  complete: function(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    if(this.settings.onComplete){
      this.settings.onComplete();
    }
  },

  formatNumber: function(n){
    var s = String(n);
    if(s.length == 1){
      s = '0' + s;
    }
    return s;
  }
}

module.exports = CountdownTimer;
```

I'm calling it in my app.js like this:

```
var timer = new require('./countdown.js').CountdownTimer({
    seconds: 80000,
    onTick: function(){
      //do something
    },
    onComplete: function(){
      alert('complete');
    }
  });

timer.start();
```

The error I'm currently getting is:

> TypeError: Object function (options){
>
> this.settings = $.extend(           {
>                             seconds: 60,
>                             onTick: null,
>                             onComplete: null            },options || {}); } has no method 'CountdownTimer'

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you making use of jQuery.noConflict(); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The require system makes an empty `module.exports` object that you can add properties to, but in your code you are overwriting that with your `CountdownTimer` function.  What you really want to do is add a `CountdownTimer` property to the `module.exports` object.

In other words instead of:

```
module.exports = CountdownTimer;
```

write:

```
module.exports.CountdownTimer = CountdownTimer;
```

Then when you `require('./countdown.js');` it'll return the what you want.  Which looks something like this:

```
{
    'CountdownTimer': function CountdownTimer() { ... }
}
```

Comment: So that was one of the variations I had tried, but it would get an error that timer.start() was not part of the object. I was doing var timer = require('./countdown.js').CountdownTimer({}) and tried simply require('/countdown.js')  then timer = new CountdownTimer({})

Comment: `var timer = require('./countdown.js').CountdownTimer({})` is missing the new operator.

Comment: Also require doesn't insert anything into the global scope.  So for the second line you tried, you have to assign the return value of the require call to a variable like so: `var countdown = require('./countdown.js'); var timer = new countdown.CountdownTimer({});`